# Как перевести стороннюю программу в фоновый режим, используя её айди?

Tags: c#

Возможно ли такое? Можно скрыть программу таким образом:

```
    ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
    si.UseShellExecute = true;
    si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Но в таком случае, можно лишь запустить какой-нибудь файл, а я бы хотел скрывать работающие программы, указав айди, как, например, здесь:

```
    Process si = Process.GetProcessById(18304);
```

Вот так, к сожалению, не получится:

```
 Process si = Process.GetProcessById(18304);
 si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Есть ещё подобные варианты, или альтернатива?

Comment: Сторонняя программа это консоль или окно?

Comment: ну, допустим, Блокнот, или Фотографии, нужно это перевести в фоновый режим

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Придется использовать WinAPI:

```
private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hWnd, int nCmdShow);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.ProcessName == 18304) // ищем по id
        {
            int hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // скрываем
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL); // показываем
        }
    }
}
```